# App Crashes with NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: ios, core-data, uicollectionview

I have a view containing some informations loaded from my CoreData. It's working in general, but some time the application crashes with this error.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '<DocumentCollectionViewCell: 0x7fb3bd0201b0; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (0 0; 107 147); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fb3bd01eb10>>: An -observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: message was received but not handled.
Key path: syncStatus
Observed object: <Document: 0x7fb3bd124570> (entity: Document; id: 0xd000000000500006 <x-coredata://CC1300FC-9C3A-4E58-8CCE-3F90C1E64718/Document/p20> ; data: {
    createdAt = nil;
    deleted = 0;
    event = "0xd000000000040008 <x-coredata://CC1300FC-9C3A-4E58-8CCE-3F90C1E64718/Note/p1>";
    localFilePath = "/Users/AliCheriaa/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CEBD0938-6989-4173-9E94-6676B0D45BB5/data/Applications/0D94B2FA-D71D-434F-9082-E26E2FBF0893/Documents/1D43AE28-E7DB-4828-8A98-DB7BF159C273/IMG";
    mimeType = "image/jpeg";
    syncProgress = 0;
    syncStatus = 0;
    user = "0xd000000000040004 <x-coredata://CC1300FC-9C3A-4E58-8CCE-3F90C1E64718/User/p1>";
    uuid = "1D43AE28-E7DB-4828-8A98-DB7BF159C273";
})
Change: {
    kind = 1;
    new = 0;
}
```

I don't really know if this is a Core Data exception or UIViewCollection exception, and how I could eventually fix it.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I would first try to narrow it down from possible errors. 
My first suggestion would be to remove the class "DocumentCollectionViewCell" from the cell and see if that still causes the crash.
If it does, then it is related to your DocumentCollectionViewCell class and more than likely the error is related to the initialization of the cell.
if it doesnt, then it is further up the stack and probably in your delegate of your CollectionView.

The error looks like KVO is failing, so maybe consider removing any core data calls from the DocumentCollectionViewCell and the delegate.